# Im not able to mock ServiceBusReceivedMessage and ServiceBusMessageActions

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, azure-functions, azureservicebus

we want to write unit-test for servicebus message trigger. we are using [Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/) nuget package

```
     [FunctionName("serviebustrigger")]
  public async Task Run ([ServiceBusTrigger("xxxxtopic", "xxxxsubscription", Connection = "Abs-Connection", AutoCompleteMessages = false)] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message, ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)

    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(Run)} execution started for MessageId:{{MessageId}}", message.MessageId);
        try
        {
                //some code
             await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
         {
             await messageActions.DeadLetterMessageAsync(message);
         }
    }
```

Now I want to write unit test for the above code. But I'm not able mock **ServiceBusReceivedMessage**  and  **ServiceBusMessageActions**  as these have Internal Constructor. Can someone suggest me better way to write unit test

Comment: "//some code" presumably represents the business logic the function implements. The ASB framework already works and has been tested by Microsoft so just test the business code, designing it to be testable without a framework such as ASB. i.e. ServiceBusReceivedMessage contains the data the business logic needs. Mock that data instead.

Answer (score 37):

There was an oversight with the implementation of `ServiceBusMessageActions` where the mocking constructor was initially missed.  This was corrected in [v5.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus/5.2.0) of the extensions package.

With that fix, a parameterless constructor is available to ensure that `ServiceBusMessageActions` is usable with a mocking framework such as Moq or FakeItEasy.  Each of the public members are `virtual` or settable and the class is not sealed.  You should be able to mock using the same approach that you prefer for other types - whether with a mocking framework or inheriting from the class and creating your own mock type - and make use of the model factory to simulate behavior.

For `ServiceBusReceivedMessage` and other model types that are returned by service operations, the [ServiceBusModelFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com//dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusmodelfactory) is used to create instances for testing purposes.